# Bootstrap 5 not working with e-junkie shopping cart

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I was using Bootstrap 4 and [E-junkie](https://www.e-junkie.com/) shopping cart. I then wanted to update to using Bootstrap 5 and I had a problem that on smaller screens the navbar showed the collapse button but it did not work when clicked. I made some bootstrap 5 fixes to navbar and simplified code and found the issue is the Javascript required by e-junkie to show the shopping cart.

If I look at the developer tools in Firefox, I see an error when I click the button:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.Event is not a function
    trigger event-handler.js:274
    show collapse.js:129
    toggle collapse.js:107
    <anonymous> collapse.js:287
    n event-handler.js:118
event-handler.js:274:22
    trigger event-handler.js:274
    show collapse.js:129
    toggle collapse.js:107
    <anonymous> collapse.js:287
    n event-handler.js:118
```

But I don't understand it.

Full example below:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>SongKong Music Tagger</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<!-- /head -->
<body style="padding-top: 100px;">

<!-- header -->
<div class="container-fluid fixed-top" style="background-image: url(/songkong/images/songkongheader.png);">
    <div class="navbar container-fluid navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark mx-auto justify-content-center">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.jthink.net/songkong/en/news.jsp">
                    News
                </a>
                 <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.fatfreecartpro.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&ejc=2&cl=347010" target="ej_ejc" onclick="return EJEJC_lc(this);">
                View Cart
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- footer -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">function EJEJC_lc(th) { return false; }; </script>
<script src="https://www.fatfreecartpro.com/ecom/box_fb_n.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Collapse button doesn't work, but if I comment out the line

```
<script src="https://www.fatfreecartpro.com/ecom/box_fb_n.js" type="text/javascript">
```

then it does work (but of course the shopping cart then doesn't work).

Content of the Javascript is:

```
/*var d = document;
var EJV1_cart_version = 1;
var EJV1_loadFlag = false;  // this defines whether or not box.js should search for ?cl

var url = "https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/box.js";
var t=d.createElement('script');
    t.setAttribute('src', url);
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(t);*/

var d = document;
var EJV1_cart_version = 1;
var EJV1_loadFlag = false;      // this defines whether or not box.js should search for ?cl
var EJV1_box_preloaded = true;
var url = "https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/restified/checkStatusL.php?cl="+EJV1_cart_version;
var t=d.createElement('script');
    t.setAttribute('src', url);
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(t);
```

How I fix the Javascript so it is compatible with Bootstrap 5?

**Update** I can see the javascript has a load of defunct lines at start,i did add it my example directly with defunct lines removed but that made no difference.

```
......
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">function EJEJC_lc(th) { return false; }; </script>
<script>
var d = document;
var EJV1_cart_version = 1;
var EJV1_loadFlag = false;      // this defines whether or not box.js should search for ?cl
var EJV1_box_preloaded = true;
var url = "https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/restified/checkStatusL.php?cl="+EJV1_cart_version;
var t=d.createElement('script');
    t.setAttribute('src', url);
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(t);   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also even if I remove the View Cart button from the navbar it still causes an issue. So I guess that clicking the collapse button is causing it to be called when we don't even want to call it but I don't understand how it works.

https://www.e-junkie.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: bootstrap and e-junkie shopping cart are not compatible. Contact the makers and ask them if they can fix it.

Long answer: you can remedy this.

The thing is: `bootstrap` does not need `jQuery`, but if `jQuery` is present, `bootstrap` implements some of its methods, so you can use `jQuery` syntax in combination with `bootstrap`. See the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/):

> Bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jQuery, but it’s still possible to use our components with jQuery. If Bootstrap detects jQuery in the window object it’ll add all of our components in jQuery’s plugin system; this means you’ll be able to do $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() to enable tooltips. The same goes for our other components.

Now, for `e-junkie` a similar thing is implemented. If `e-junkie` notices that `jQuery` is not loaded on the page, it will add its own implementation of `jQuery` to the page. This implementation is rudimentary: it only implements some methods needed by `e-junkie`, not all of it.

Once `e-junkie` has added `jQuery` to the page, that's when the problems start. `bootstrap` thinks `jQuery` is installed and tries to work with `e-junkie`'s implementation. But the original `jQuery` that `bootstrap` thinks is there, is actually a stripped down version implemented by `e-junkie`. Hence the warning emitted by `bootstrap` that the `Event` property of the `jQuery` object is not a function.

Now, there are two things you can do: add `jQuery` to the page yourself. You should add that before your `bootstrap` and `e-junkie` scripts. If you're using the latest `jQuery` version (currently 3.7.0), you should also add jquery-migrate, since `bootstrap 5` is not compatible with the latest version. (jquery-migrate makes sure `jQuery` is backwards compatible.)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

An easier solution is to tell `bootstrap` to NOT use `jQuery`, even if it is loaded on the page. You can do this by adding the following attribute to the `body` tag:

```
<body style="padding-top: 100px;" data-bs-no-jquery="true">
```

See `bootstrap`'s [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#jquery-events):

> Bootstrap will detect jQuery if jQuery is present in the window object and there is no data-bs-no-jquery attribute set on `<body>`.

Problem solved: `bootstrap` will stay away from `jQuery` and not use the `jQuery` object created by `e-junkie`.

Comment: Thankyou great answer, and applied and worked. I missed my bounty expiration but I have started another bounty and will apply to this answer when i can.